# Waiting for a method to finish using C#?

Tags: c#, file-io, file-upload

I have method which writes a file to the local disk. Another method takes that file and uploads it to a sftp server. The problem is, that the file on the sftp server is empty. This is a small piece of my code:

```
WriteToLocalFolder(content, filename);
WriteToSftpServer(filename, server logon params);
```

Could it be that *WriteToSftpServer* gets called before *WriteToLocalFolder* finished writing? If yes, how can I say that *WriteToSftpServer* should start only after *WriteToLocalFolder* has finished writing the file?

*WriteToLocalFolder* looks like this in the real code:

```
 public static void WriteToFolder(StringBuilder content, string whereTo)
 {
    File.WriteAllText(whereTo, content.ToString());
 }
```

So the stream is closed I think...

Thanks :-)

Comment: Is the code in WriteToLocalFolder closing the file?

Comment: Depends on whether the methods are synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: Can you post the source code of `WriteToLocalFolder()`?

Comment: the problem is maybe in the code of the `WriteToLocalFolder` method. I bet there is flush or close method missing on the filestream. Can you post you code ?

Comment: It is just as likely that the SFTP transfer failed.  I'll flip a coin, you call heads or tails.

Comment: How does `WriteToLocalFolder(filename)` end you up in a function with a signature `WriteToFolder(StringBuilder,string)`?

Comment: It was just pseudocode, but I updated it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `WriteToSftpServer` shouldn't ever happen before `WriteToLocalFolder` is done (because it does not seem to be async).  However it could be that filestream is not properly closed and so `WriteToSftpServer` can't access it.

Try getting a breakpoint inside `WriteToSftpServer` where the file gets loaded to see what does it load. You can always "step next" inside the method, if the file loads correctly, to see where does it break.

Comment: +1. That's where I would start out as well. At that breakpoint, it's easy to look at the file on disk and see what actually is attempted to transfer to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If WriteToLocalFolder doesn't spawn a separate thread, this is **NOT** possible. Maybe you are missing a `Stream.Flush`, `Stream.Close` or `Stream.Dispose` in any of the methods?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code in `WriteToLocalFolder`, but it sounds more likely that you're writing content to the file and forgetting to `Flush` the write buffer. If this is not the case, please edit your question and add the code for `WriteToLocalFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
  {
     WriteToLocalFolder(content, filename);

  } while ((System.IO.File.Exists(filename) != true));


WriteToSftpServer(filename, server logon params);
```

this loop will ensure that the file exists with its content befor getting to the next line..